# Select com PDO e SQL barrando HTML

Tags: html, sql, pdo, aplicação-web

Estou tentando fazer um Select com o PDO e MYSQL, porém quando eu coloco o código php fazendo essa consulta no meio do meu html ele não permite a execução do restante da página.

**segue o trecho do código:**

```
<select class="emselect">
    <option value="select">selecione</option>
    <?php
    $buscarid=$pdo->prepare("SELECT ID,usuario FROM usuarios ORDER BY ID ASC");
    $buscarid->execute();
    while($linha=$buscarid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value=".$linha["ID"].$linha["usuario"].">".$linha["ID"]." ".$linha["usuario"]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </option>
</select>
```

Após tentar fazer alguns teste percebi que o problema era no php, porém não esta ligado a nenhum tipo de fechamento "aberto", algo que já me deu problema anteriormente, então acredito que a conexão no meio do código html esteja o barrando, logo qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Preciso que o while continue no mesmo lugar para listar os itens do select.

Comment: Você fez a conexão antes de fazer o `prepare`? Não esta emitindo nenhuma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não havia me tocado! era exatamente isso, esta página estava sendo executada após efetuar o login, acabei deixando passar a conexão nela pois já havia colocado na anterior, acho que pensei que por estar na mesma sessão iria continuar, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Problema resolvido como sugerido por Roberto de Campos, não havia feito a conexão anteriormente.

Comment: aceita a resposta dele então

Comment: Wel, nesse caso deves marcar a outra resposta como aceite, com esse ✔ verde.

Comment: ele me respondeu no comentário, a resposta que ele fez aqui não resolve o problema, caso ele coloque o que disse no comentário como resposta irei aceita-la.

Comment: @Wel, resposta alterada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente faltou você fazer a conexão antes de utilizar a função `prepare`, você pode fazer isso dessa forma:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seu_banco_de_dados', 'seu_usuario', 'sua_senha');
```

Agora a partir da variável `$conn` que é onde está a sua conexão, você executa o `prepare` e atribui a sua variável `$buscarid`:

```
<select class="emselect">
    <option value="select">selecione</option>
    <?php
    $buscarid = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, usuario FROM usuarios ORDER BY ID ASC");
    $buscarid->execute();
    while($linha=$buscarid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value=".$linha["ID"].$linha["usuario"].">".$linha["ID"]." ".$linha["usuario"]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Porém, dessa forma vai exigir que você repita o código para fazer a conexão todas as vezes que necessitar se conectar ao banco de dados. Se necessário uma manutenção no seu sistema, você poderá ter uma dor de cabeça.
Para evitar essa repetição de código, você pode criar uma classe onde a conexão será criada, para isso crie um novo arquivo `PHP` chamado `conexao.class.php` e coloque o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?
    class Conexao extends PDO { // Criamos a classe Conexao que estende todas os métodos e propriedades da classe PDO

        private static $instancia; // Criamos uma variável $instancia que é onde a instancia do PDO ficará quando criada

        //Este método abaixo é o construtor, ou seja, ele será executado quando for criada uma nova instancia da nossa classe Conexao.
        public function Conexao($dsn, $username, $password){
            parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);//Aqui estamos chamando o método construtor da classe pai que no nosso caso é PDO
        }

        //Este método, será responsável por criar a conexão ou retornar a conexão existente
        public static function getInstance(){
            if (!isset(self::$instancia)){ //Se a variável $instancia não estiver setada, a conexão será criada
                try{
                    //Neste ponto criamos uma instancia da classe Conexao e armazenamos ela dentro da variável $instancia
                    self::$instancia = new Conexao("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=seu_banco_de_dados",
                        "seu_usuario", "sua_senha");
                } catch (Exception $e) { //Em caso de erro ao tentar se conectar será retornada uma string com o erro
                    return "Ocorreu um erro ao conectar!<br />".$e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            return self::$instancia; //Caso der tudo certo será retornada a Conexao criada
        }
    }
?>
```

O seu código para recuperar os usuários ficaria assim:

```
<?
    include_once 'conexao.class.php';
    $conn = Conexao::getInstance();
    if (!is_string($conn)) { //Se a variável $conn não for uma string a conexão foi efetuada com sucesso
        ?>
            <select class="emselect">
                <option value="select">selecione</option>
                <?
                    $buscarid = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, usuario FROM usuarios ORDER BY ID ASC");
                    $buscarid->execute();
                    while($linha=$buscarid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        echo "<option value=".$linha["ID"].$linha["usuario"].">".$linha["ID"]." ".$linha["usuario"]."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        <?
    } else {//Caso a variável $conn seja uma string, ela conterá o erro que ocorreu na conexão
        echo $conn;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Acredito que esse não seja o problema, pelo que tinha observado o problema está no execute do PDO, em qualquer lugar que eu coloquei ele no meio do meu código, todo o código abaixo em html simplesmente não executa.

Comment: @Roberto dá uma olhada nos comentários da outra resposta

Comment: @Math Obrigado pelo comentário, acabei de implementar a resposta